# What new (if any) distribution/provisioning do I need for a 1.1 version of my App?

Tags: iphone, version, distribution

Do I need to create a new distribution certificate or anything special before building and uploading to Apple a new version of my existing app?

Or do I keep everything else the same as before save the version & build info?

Thanks!
Henry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to keep everything the same as long as you update version info. Unless your profile has expired.